# How install alpha version package via npm?

Tags: laravel, npm, bootstrap-5

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Installs  bootstrap 4.5, which is latest stable version

```
npm install bootstrap 5.0.0-alpha1
```

returns error

```
ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap@^5
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I need bootstrap 5 for Laravel project
how install it ?

Comment: Just include css and js links mentioned in here: https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: You're missing the `@` symbol. Run the following command instead `npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: Thanks , this works @STA mentioned that it is not possible, but 
`npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1`  works  without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot the `@` sign, otherwise there are no problems installing bootstrap 5 alpha version via npm.

```
npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1
```

Answer (score 2):

`npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1` (or any other alpha version) wasn't working for me, but after reading the latest alpha-3 release post [here](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/11/11/bootstrap-5-alpha-3/) I realised the following works:

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```